# Error Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception in Spring Boot 3.1.2 using jdk 20 & JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-20

Everything was working fine when we were using JDK 11 and Spring Boot 2.4 but we have upgraded from:
Spring boot 2.4 to 3.1.2
java 11 to java 20
and few more upgrades
We are also using mapstructs in project.

Getting Error when I am trying to fetch the data of Invities from AccountsEntity in the below code. Invities Entity has One to Many kind of relationship with Accounts.

```java
Set<AccountsEntity> accountsEntitiesForAdmin = accountsRepo.findAllByAccountOwnerAndIsActiveTrue(requestingUser)
                .orElse(null);
```

AccountsEntity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_account")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class AccountsEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tbl_account_id_pk")
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name = "account_name")
    private String accountName;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "account_type")
    private AccountType accountType;

    @Column(name = "account_image")
    private String accountImage;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_app_user_creator_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "tbl_app_user_id_pk")
    private RegisteredProfileEntity appUserCreator;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_app_user_owner_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "tbl_app_user_id_pk")
    private RegisteredProfileEntity accountOwner;

    @Column(name = "creation_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime creationDateTime;
    
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime updationDateTime;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Long createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Long updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<MembersEntity> appMembers;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private Set<InvitationEntity> invities;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accounts")
    private Set<TwilioUnassignedNumberEntity> twilioUnassignedNumbers;
    
    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;
```

InvitationEntity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_invitation_app_and_nonapp")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class InvitationEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tbl_invitation_id_pk")
    private Long invitationId;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private StatusTypeEnum statusTypeEnum;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "module_type")
    private ModuleType moduleType;

    @Column(name = "sms")
    private String sms;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_account_id_fk")
    private AccountsEntity account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_conference_id_fk")
    private ConferenceEntity conference;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_group_id_fk")
    private GroupEntity group;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_twilio_phone_number_id_fk")
    private TwilioPhoneNumberEntity twilioPhoneNumberEntity;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "twilio_phone_number_type")
    private TwilioPhoneNumberType twilioPhoneNumberType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_app_user_sender_fk")
    private RegisteredProfileEntity sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_app_user_reciever_fk")
    private RegisteredProfileEntity reciever;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_non_app_user_id_fk")
    private NonAppUserEntity nonAppUser;

    @Column(name = "creation_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime creationDateTime;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime updationDateTime;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Long createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Long updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    
    @Column(name = "twilio_sender_reciept")
    private String twilioSenderReciept;
    
    @Column(name = "reinvite_count")
    private int reInviteCount;
```

[image: Debugging window image showing the issue]

in application.proerties made these two entries run with latest upgrades for testing.

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

we are expecting that

```java
Set<AccountsEntity> accountsEntitiesForAdmin = accountsRepo.findAllByAccountOwnerAndIsActiveTrue(requestingUser)
                .orElse(null);
```

this should give the result but its giving us the error.

Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception.

Index 50 out of bounds for length 4

DB Query result image:

[image: DB Query result image]

Postman hit:

[image: Postman hit]

Comment: I'd start the research with enabling Hibernate's SQL logging, finding resulting query in your logs and running it as native query. Maybe that will give you some insight

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thanks for providing your time in helping, I have executed the log queries and they are giving the result but i think its not working with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution but donot why it is not working with upgrade as you can see I have used a enum in the invitation entity which is directly used

```
@Column(name = "status")
private StatusTypeEnum statusTypeEnum;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "module_type")
private ModuleType moduleType;
```

StatusTypeEnum without enumerated as string is not working in my case but after placing the same it worked.

Any thought on this community

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. For me, my field type in the database is varchar. After testing, if the field type changed to int, there will not be any problems.